# Is it possible to place a button on a google calendar?

Tags: google-apps-script

I know it can be done on a spreadsheet, like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n2lIZ.png), but is it possible to place a button on a google calendar?  If not, do you know of something similar that might work?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to inject code HTML code in the description of an event, yet a button in the UI of a google calendar, no

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-app#createeventtitle-starttime-endtime-options

in the attribute options you'll find the description